# OpenRewrite recipe specified in rewrite.yml with values for all mandatory properties fails because the recipe does not receive the values

Tags: java, maven, recipe, openrewrite

I am trying to replicate SayHelloRecipe example from the OpenRewrite documentation. My recipe is as follows:

```
package my.package.recipes;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Value;
import org.openrewrite.Cursor;
import org.openrewrite.ExecutionContext;
import org.openrewrite.Option;
import org.openrewrite.Recipe;
import org.openrewrite.TreeVisitor;
import org.openrewrite.internal.lang.NonNull;
import org.openrewrite.java.JavaIsoVisitor;
import org.openrewrite.java.JavaTemplate;
import org.openrewrite.java.tree.J;

@Value
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class SayHelloRecipe extends Recipe {
    @Option(displayName = "Fully Qualified Class Name",
            description = "A fully qualified class name indicating which class to add a hello() method to.",
            example = "com.yourorg.FooBar")
    @NonNull
    String fullyQualifiedClassName;

    @JsonCreator
    public SayHelloRecipe(@NonNull @JsonProperty("fullyQualifiedClassName") String fullyQualifiedClassName) {
        this.fullyQualifiedClassName = fullyQualifiedClassName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return "Say Hello";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Adds a \"hello\" method to the specified class.";
    }

    @Override
    public TreeVisitor<?, ExecutionContext> getVisitor() {
        return new SayHelloVisitor();
    }

    public class SayHelloVisitor extends JavaIsoVisitor<ExecutionContext> {
        private final JavaTemplate helloTemplate =
                JavaTemplate.builder( "public String hello() { return \"Hello from #{}!\"; }")
                        .build();
        @Override
        public J.ClassDeclaration visitClassDeclaration(J.ClassDeclaration classDecl, ExecutionContext executionContext) {
            if (classDecl.getType() == null || !classDecl.getType().getFullyQualifiedName().equals(fullyQualifiedClassName)) {
                return classDecl;
            }

            boolean helloMethodExists = classDecl.getBody().getStatements().stream()
                    .filter(statement -> statement instanceof J.MethodDeclaration)
                    .map(J.MethodDeclaration.class::cast)
                    .anyMatch(methodDeclaration -> methodDeclaration.getName().getSimpleName().equals("hello"));

            if (helloMethodExists) {
                return classDecl;
            }

            classDecl = classDecl.withBody( helloTemplate.apply(new Cursor(getCursor(), classDecl.getBody()),
                    classDecl.getBody().getCoordinates().lastStatement(),
                    fullyQualifiedClassName ));

            return classDecl;
        }
    }
}
```

The recipe compiles and its tests pass. I then have a different project with some sample code to which I want to apply some built-in recipes and this custom recipe. To this end, I have included in this other project a rewrite.yml file in the root of the project:

```
---
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: my.package.recipes.AddHelloMethod
recipeList:
  - my.package.recipes.SayHelloRecipe:
      fullyQualifiedClassName: 'another.package.openrewritedemo.controller.MessageController'
```

The Maven configuration for the OpenRewrite plugin is as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.2</version>
    <configuration>
       <activeRecipes>
          <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.OrderImports</recipe>
          <recipe>org.openrewrite.staticanalysis.CommonStaticAnalysis</recipe>
          <recipe>org.openrewrite.staticanalysis.JavaApiBestPractices</recipe>
          <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.UpgradeSpringBoot_3_0</recipe>
          <recipe>my.package.recipes.SayHelloRecipe</recipe>
       </activeRecipes>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
          <artifactId>rewrite-spring</artifactId>
          <version>5.0.10</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
          <artifactId>rewrite-static-analysis</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.7</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
          <artifactId>CustomRecipe</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

All of this seems correct to me, however when I try to run the project where I want to use my custom recipe, it throws an error stating "Recipe validation error in fullyQualifiedClassName: is required", and by adding log statements to the recipe I have verified that fullyQualifiedClassName is null, as if it didn't receive the value specified in the rewrite.yml file. What can I do so the recipe will receive the value specified in the rewrite.yml file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: All of that looks OK to me; are there any other fields in `SayHelloRecipe` that might cause the `@Value` annotation to create another constructor? It's hard to say with a limited view on your code. Perhaps a minimal reproduction sample could help here?

Comment: @Tim Thanks for reviewing it. I have included the full code of the recipe, I hope that will help. One thing that I noticed reading the documentation, but didn't work to solve the problem, is that I originally had mistakenly placed the rewrite.yml file in the project where I wanted to use the recipe, whereas it's apparently meant to be part of the jar of the recipe. But as I said, that didn't work. I also ran other experiments, making the recipe and the project where I want to apply it be modules of the same multimodule project, for example, but all to no avail.

Comment: Which path are you using in your library? It should be `src/main/resource/META-INF/rewrite/rewrite.yml` or similar, as seen in https://github.com/moderneinc/rewrite-recipe-starter/blob/main/src/main/resources/META-INF/rewrite/rewrite.yml

Comment: You can also start with a fork of moderneinc/rewrite-recipe-starter to get started with a working library setup.

Comment: Yes, it is in that route, and I've verified that it ends up in the jar for the recipe. In fact, after putting it in the correct route, the logs started to show both a call that showed the null value, and one that showed the right value. The recipe validation error, of course, still happens, as the first time the recipe is initialized, the property does not receive the value from the file for some reason, even though there's a subsequent call in which it does. I will try the fork approach that you suggest, hopefully that produces better results.

Comment: @Tim Problem solved. The recipe name in the maven plugin configuration was incorrect :(

Comment: Glad to hear your issue was resolved!